# TM - Clustering data with special date variable

Tags: r, cluster-computing, tm

Ive got the following data from tripadvisor:

```
'data.frame':   682 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ id           : Factor w/ 674 levels "id","rn106322397",..: 672 671 670 669 668 667 666 665 664 663 ...
 $ quote        : Factor w/ 606 levels "\"Picturesque Lake Konigssee\"",..: 389 139 113 149 384 39 176 598 199 603 ...
 $ rating       : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 4 5 ...
 $ date         : Factor w/ 505 levels "date","Reviewed 1 August 2014\n",..: 200 200 427 427 427 443 434 351 313 494 ...
 $ reviewnospace: Factor w/ 674 levels "- Good car parking facilities- Organized boat trips- Ensure that you have enough time at hand for the boat trip",..: 624 573 144 211 507 26 351 672 451 249 ...
```

I try to cluster the data on the basis of the date, to get two groups - winter and summer vacationers. With this clustering i want to analyse the reviews afterwards. I am using the tm package and tried it with the following code:

```
> x <- read.csv ("seeganz.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
> corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(x$reviewnospace), readerControl = list(language = "eng"))
> meta(corp,tag = "date") <- x$date
> idx <- meta(corp, "date") == 'December'
```

But it is not working as the content say 0 documents:

```
> corp [idx]
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 1
Content:  documents: 0
```

As the date has the structure "*Reviewed 1 August 2014*", how do I have to adapt this code to get, for example just the reviews from Nov - Feb?

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generic Approach:

- Use `substr(date, 10, nchar(date))` to get to `1 August 2014` call this new vector dateNew
- Use normal date function e.g. as.Date(dateNew,...) to change dateNew into a vector of type Date where you can do subsetting/subtraction and other operations
  References from http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

  ```
  # use as.Date( ) to convert strings to dates 
  mydates <- as.Date(c("2007-06-22", "2004-02-13"))
  # number of days between 6/22/07 and 2/13/04 
  days <- mydates[1] - mydates[2]
  ```

Comment: thank you for your reply! I tried it with the following code `> dateNew <- substr(date, 9, 24)
> dateNew
 [1] " 27 October 2015" " 25 October 2015" " 23 October 2015" " 23 October 2015"
 [5] " 21 October 2015" " 21 October 2015" " 21 October 2015" " 18 October 2015"
 [9] " 18 October 2015" " 17 October 2015"
    > as.Date(dateNew, "%d %B %Y")
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`             But why do I get NAs??

Comment: @LauraHiemer: updated answer please review. Thanks. Plus, I think you need to try nchar(date) as opposed to the number 24. The reason is nchar("Reviewed 25 October 2015") = 24 and nchar("Reviewed 25 August 2015") = 23.